# Most efficient way of representing a two dimensional grid in Python

Tags: python, graph

I am new to Python and have been trying my hand at some programming problems to get a better hold of the language.
So far I've read Guido's essay at https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/ . This has helped me understand how to work with graphs.
But, competitive programming problems mostly have two dimensional grids:

```
U..X
..X.
X..X
..X.
```

How do I represent those in Python? Is a list of lists a good representation? Is there a better or more "Pythonic" method? Thanks.

Comment: For future developments in graph try `NetworkX` it is easy to use as `Python` itself.

Answer (score 2):

A list of lists is usually fine for most uses of grids, but if you're interested in doing more advanced things with two-dimensional arrays, you probably want to look into [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).  NumPy is implemented in C, and is very efficient; it has a lot more capabilities than you're looking for, but it's worth a look anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, nested lists are generally the way to go - it allows easy access to a point on the 'grid' provided the indices are already known - `grid[y][x]`.

Printing them in grid form is trivial as well:

```
for i in grid:
    print i
```